# Is there a way to create database and seed data in asp.net core 2 when changing the connection string

Tags: multi-tenant, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way to create the database and seed data in asp.net core 2 when changing the connection string through the OnConfiguring method of the DbContext?

I have designed my app for multi-tenancy (multi-database model) and should be able to register tenants dynamically each with connection string. Now my problem is, how can I create the database and seed data dynamically without restarting the app?

[OnConfiguring screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K7Xh.png)

Comment: So you seem you have found a solution, would you mind to share some guidance how to do this?

Comment: @ibubi I used dependency injection. First you need to have some kind of identifier that tells you what tenant is accessing the endpoints and what type of database it's using together with its connection string. I used a middleware that reads http headers or antoher way is by reading the host url to determine the tenant. Then the tenant info is stored to the http context which is then passed into custom services registration in the DI container.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the process of provisioning a database for a new tenant would require some time. Hence, you could follow the below steps.

1. Create a new tenant in the code
2. Post a message to the service bus with the necessary information like the tenanid / name etc.
3. Have a job ( typically the web Job) listen to the messages and run restore a new database from a master dacpac or script. Finally rename the database to the tenant.
4. Push back a message via service bus to let the application know about the database.
5. On receipt of the above message, the application updates the connection details for the tenant in the database.

In the other option, you can take a look at the Azure shard map for the tenant database sharding.

HTH

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @JeonsoftFaceBundy did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @JohanJvRensburg Yes, I had to use another DI container, StructureMap, and use SaasKit for multi-tenancy: https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit

Comment: @JeonsoftFaceBundy exactly what I did as well :)